# When I add a new board to an Organisation, other Organisation members on iPhones are not notified it even exists.

Tags: iphone, trello-organization

Both iPhone users in the same Organisation. If I add a new board I should be able to task other members without having to tell then about the new board and them having to join first.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Trello support